# TCPDF and Colorbox

Tags: php, jquery, forms, colorbox, tcpdf

I'm trying to display a pdf generated with TCPDF, but i see just a long string of stranghe characters like this: 1���� ��<���A

I'm using jquery to pass form POST variables to a page (printPDFfromForm.php) that generate a pdf file with TCPDF

Jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$("#formID").submit(function() {
    $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function(data) {$.colorbox({html:data});},'html');
    return false;
});
```

});

html code

```
<form action='printPDFfromForm.php' id="formID" method='POST'>
```

Where i've did wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: please provide string which you are displaying on pdf

Comment: what do you need? file "printPDFfromForm.php looks like this

http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_002.phps

Comment: I think you need to use **ob_clean()** before PDF output.

Comment: without use of colorbox, pdf file is generating fine.